# Google Maps JS - Touch/click, drag, triggers zoom to max

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps JS Api, Using a chrome with Mobile rendering or an Android device, attempting to pan the map results in zooming to the max zoom.

I've tried using the options for "gestureHandling" (greedy, cooperative, none, auto) none corrects the issue.
I did notice in Chrome Dev tools that there are event handlers attached to both the mousedown and touchstart events on the map's div.
Removing the mousedown event corrects the issue but not sure how to apply that programmatically.

This is the code in the AngularJs controller for the map.

```
   vm.map;

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            var map = document.getElementById('map');
            vm.map = new google.maps.Map(
                map,
                {
                    zoom: 11,
                    minZoom: 5,
                    maxZoom: 16,
                    center: vm.location,
                    fullscreenControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    zoomControl: false,
                    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
                    scrollWheel: false
                }
            );

        });
```

Here is the Html

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="start center" ng-controller="locationsCtrl as vm">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="position: relative;">

         <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:520px;" ></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The google maps script is loaded in the index.html before the controller is loaded.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=weekly&key=MY_KEY"></script>
```

I expect pan/zoom to pan with single finger, zoom on pinch or double tap but panning with a single finger or mouse, zooms to the maxZoom value.

Update:
Added event listeners for dragStart, drag and dragEnd show that dragEnd is not firing on a mouseUp.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here.

[Google Maps API gesture handling not working with AngularJS Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592964/google-maps-api-gesture-handling-not-working-with-angularjs-material)

```
 angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .config(function($mdGestureProvider) {
    // For mobile devices without jQuery loaded, do not
    // intercept click events during the capture phase.
    $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
  });
```